# Describing oscillation from x(t) and y(t)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am doing exercises from Gilbert Strang's *Calculus*. Please note that at this point, the author has not yet introduced the formal definition of derivatives nor the concept of limits. However, he has explained informally by means of algebra, geometry and physics the following pairs of distance and velocity.

1. linear motion: $f(t) = \frac 1 2at^2$ and $v(t) = at$
2. circular motion: $f(t) = sin(t)$ and $v(t) = cos(t)$, and $f(t) = cos(t)$ and $v(t) = -sin(t)$

The title question looks like this:

> The oscillation $x = 0$, $y = sin(t)$ goes
>
> 1. up and down
> 2. between $-1$ and $1$
> 3. starting from $x = 0$, $y = 0$
> 4. at velocity $v = cos(t)$.
>
> Find (1)(2)(3)(4) for the oscillations 31-36.

Two of them are unusual in that they are not simply horizontal or vertical movements.

> $x=cos(t)$, $y = cos(t)$

We observe that $x = y$ for any $t$, with $-1 < x = y < 1$. Therefore, oscillation goes

1. in an oblique line y = x
2. between $(-1, -1)$ and $(1, 1)$
3. starting from $x = 1$, $y = 1$.

Both x and y components of the velocity are $-sin(t)$. In the $y = x$ direction, the velocity is

4. $v = \sqrt {(-sin(t))^2 + (-sin(t))^2} = \sqrt2sin(t)$.

Is my answer correct?

The next one is more challenging:

> $x=cos^2(t)$, $y = sin^2(t)$

We observe that $x + y = 1$ for any $t$ with $-1 < x, y < 1$. Therefore, oscillation goes

1. in an oblique line y = 1 - x
2. between (1, 0) and (0, 1)
3. starting from $x = 1$ and $y = 0$.

What is the velocity? We know the speed of the sine and cosine curves, but how do we know the speed of the square of the sine and cosine curves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if the author mentioned this is his book, but these are two rules that are easy to intuitively check

> 1. If the distances are stretched by a factor $\alpha$, then the velocities change by the same quantity. e.g, if $f(t) = \alpha\sin t$, then $v = \alpha\cos t$. This is easy to see, if you just change the rulers to measure distances
> 2. A similar argument applies when the clock you use to measure velocities is slowed down/sped up
> 3. If distances are measured from a point away from the origin, velocities do not change. e.g. if $f(t) = \cos t + c$ then $v = -\sin t$, with $c$ a constant.

Now all you need to do is remember that

\begin{align}
\cos^2t = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos 2t) \\
\sin^2t = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \cos 2t) \\
\end{align}

so that the velocity is then

\begin{align}
v_x = -\sin  2t \\
v_y = \sin 2t 
\end{align}

and the speed

$$
v = (v_x^2 + v_y^2)^{1/2} = 2^{1/2}\sin 2t
$$